# Set property of th onClick

Tags: reactjs

How do I set the `display style` of the header column `onClicked` below to `none` so that the column disappears?

```
class StockTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {hidden: []};
    }
    //Make the column header clicked dissapear
    handleClickTableHeaderColumn(i) {
            //**How do I get the column clicked and change the display property?**
            console.log(this);//this.state.hidden[i].event + this.state.hidden[i].name);
    }
    render () {        
        var items = [];
        for (var symbol in this.props.stocks) {
            var stock = this.props.stocks[symbol];           
            items.push(<StockRow key={stock.symbol} stock={stock} bid={this.props.bid} ask = {this.props.ask} last={this.props.last}/>);

        }            

        return (        
            <table table-head id="stocktable">
                <colgroup>
                    <col class="maroon" />                    
                </colgroup>
                <tbody> 
                <tr>                    
                    <th></th>
                    <th onClick={(i) => this.handleClickTableHeaderColumn(i)}>P/M</th> 
                    <th onClick={(i) => this.handleClickTableHeaderColumn(i)}>T</th>
                    <th onClick={(i) => this.handleClickTableHeaderColumn(i)}>K</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out:

**css**

```
.none {
    display: none;
}

handleClick(event) {
        event.currentTarget.style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: One thing I just realized. This just makes the column header disappear, not all the cells withing the column!